Error in Office Script when using forEach
This Office Script against a single Query object works:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get all the Power Query queries in the workbook.
    let query = workbook.getQuery("data");
    console.log(`Query Name: ${query.getName()}, Rows Loaded: ${query.getRowsLoadedCount()}, Loaded to: ${query.getLoadedTo()}, Loaded to Data Model:${query.getLoadedToDataModel()}, Refresh Date: ${query.getRefreshDate()}`);
}

This code that uses forEach over a collection of Query objects (taken from this Microsoft Learn sample ) does not work:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get all the Power Query queries in the workbook.
  let queries = workbook.getQueries();

  // For each query, log the date it was last refreshed.
  queries.forEach(query => {
    console.log(`Query Name: ${query.getName()}, Rows Loaded: ${query.getRowsLoadedCount()}, Loaded to: ${query.getLoadedTo()}, Loaded to Data Model:${query.getLoadedToDataModel()}, Refresh Date: ${query.getRefreshDate()}`);
  });
}

Error:
Line 7: Query getName: The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel. Please refer to the documentation: "https://docs.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets".
I don't think the error message is accurate based on the first version working.
This code:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get all the Power Query queries in the workbook.
    let queries = workbook.getQueries();
    queries.forEach(query => {
        console.log(`Query Name: ${query}`);
    });
}

Returns one line per object in the console log:
Query Name: [object Object]
Query Name: [object Object]
And at least the Intellisense thinks the object type is 'Query':

And defining the type yields the same error
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get all the Power Query queries in the workbook.
    let queries = workbook.getQueries();
    queries.forEach((query: ExcelScript.Query) => {
        console.log(`Query Name: ${query.getName()}`);
    });
}

It feels like a JavaScript error, but I'm just not seeing it!
Update
On @Rocky Sims suggestion, I tried console.log(query);, which shows the properties:
{type: "Query", instance: Object, engine: Object}
  type: "Query"
  instance: Object
    m_contextBase: Object
    m_objectPath: Object
    m_context: Object
    m_isNull: false
    m_loadedTo: "ConnectionOnly"
    m_loadedToDataModel: true
    m_name: "data"
    m_refreshDate: Wed Apr 10 2024 14:01:58 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    m_rowsLoadedCount: 44
    m_error: "None"
  engine: Object

The documentation for the Query object is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.query?view=office-scripts#method-details
You can't access the Properties except through the Get Methods:


${query} won't work, but ${query.getName()} should.

You could try console.log(query) then in the console you can expand the query object to see what properties it has (does it even have a getName property? is it a function?). That won't solve your issue but it may provide some insight.

@Barmar agreed, but it doesn't

@Rocky Sims Good suggestion. I can see the properties, but in the Object model, the properties aren't available except through the Get methods. See update at the bottom of my post for what I can see in the console log and the API doc.
